# Drupal 8 StartTLS not supported by server or could not initiate session

Tags: drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site and want to send emails using SMTP details provided by Sparkpost. I have installed the SMTP module and setup the SMTP details, however, Drupal is reporting the following error;

StartTLS not supported by server or could not initiate session.

I don't know if this means the mail server doesn't support StartTLS, or the web server the Drupal site is running on doesn't support it?

Comment: Is openssl installed?

Comment: Yes, openssl is installed. We decided to remove the sparkpost Drupal module and configure postfix to relay mail via SMTP instead.